# Retrieve GET params in KOHANA framework

Tags: php, get, routes, kohana

My url such as http://MYDOMAIN.com/cron/reports/test?code=f463529c1b75f4d868 . And I need retrieve code (f463529c1b75f4d868) . What should I do? (I'm working in Kohana)
I have route such this:

```
Route::set('cron_defaults', 'cron/<controller>(/<action>(?code=<code>))')
        ->defaults(array(
    'directory' => 'cron',
    'controller' => 'reports',
    'action' => 'test',
));
```

And in the controller reports I've written :

```
var_dump(Request::instance()->param('code'));
```

And I have NULL as result. What is wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The easiest way to resolve this problem is global array $_SERVER!

Answer (score 6):

Normally query strings should be available like this:

```
$code = $this->request->query('code');
```

Comment: I've tried this and error was "Call to undefined method Request::query()"

Comment: what version are you using ? can you also try: Request::current->query('code')

Comment: I didn't find the version of Kohana but I opened class Request and there is no method named 'query'. I suppose it's old version. But I couldn't update framework because I think old functions will stop working. Any idea what I must do?

Comment: Check `Kohana::VERSION` constant. `query` was added since `3.1` version. You should remove `?code=<code>` part and retrieve query params with `Arr::get('code', $_GET)` calls.`